# Remote host making strange request. Am I safe?

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I am starting work for an organization on their server. They need to allow connections from my server in order to use GIT over SSH.

They asked me to place this in my SSH directory:

```
SHORTNAME=abcdef
FULLNAME=12.34.56.789
PORT=9999
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_${SHORTNAME}
cat <<EOF >> ~/.ssh/config
host ${SHORTNAME}
hostname ${FULLNAME}
port ${PORT}
identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_${SHORTNAME}
compression yes
protocol 2
ServerAliveInterval 60
EOF
ssh ${SHORTNAME} "mkdir -p ~/.ssh"
scp -P ${PORT} ~/.ssh/id_rsa_${SHORTNAME}.pub ${FULLNAME}:~/.ssh/id_rsa_${SHORTNAME}.pub
ssh ${SHORTNAME} "cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_${SHORTNAME}.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

I am a Linux beginner. I just want to ensure that running this in SSH won't allow them access to my server. We're trying to achieve a solution where my server is allowed to connect to their server for push and pull requests via GIT over SSH. Is this safe to do? Or is there a better solution to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script...when run on your local system...will:

- Create a new ssh keypair for you in your `.ssh` directory.  You'll end up with two files, `id_rsa_abcdef` and `id_rsa_abcdef.pub`.
- It will create an ssh configuration file for you in `.ssh/config` with the following contents:

  ```
  host abcdef
  hostname 12.34.56.789
  port 9999
  identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_abcdef
  compression yes
  protocol 2
  ServerAliveInterval 60
  ```

  This will allow you to type `ssh abcdef`, for example, and `ssh` will know to connect to host `12.34.56.789` on port `9999` using your newly created keypair without you having to type in a bunch of additional command line options.
- It will then copy your ssh public key to the remote server so that you can use your private key for authentication.

It will not give any access to your local machine to somebody else.

Comment: Is it safe to generate the key by root? Or should I generate from a different user?

Comment: Since you're not opening up any access to your system...it doesn't really matter.  But generally you should not be doing things as root on your system.  Runnings commands as root means that a typo can be a crisis rather than an inconvenience, compare the typo `rm -rf / myfile` (whoops, there's an extra space there) run as root (it will delete everything) vs run as a normal user (it won't have permission to delete things other than  your home directory contents).

Answer (score 1):

The commands/script you posted here is safe and will create a keypair to use for SSH authentication and it will copy the public key to ${FULLNAME}. This is a good solution.